# offset in the x-axis using bar function (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I genereated a graph in matlab using the following code:

```
epsilons = 0.1:0.1:1;
RMS = zeros(length(epsilons));
%some data manipulations, changing the RMS to real values
figure;
bar(epsilons , RMS);
```

as you can see, `epsilons` contains 10 values: `0.1, 0.2, ..., 1`

however, using the `bar` function I get an offset, as can be seeb in this pic:
[image]

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You must modify the value of `epsilons` somewhere. Please provide the actual code since this clearly isn't accurate due to your bar widths not being the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These looks like your RMS is not a vector, but matrix with zero (or NAN) values outside of first column.
So, you need just display RMS first column:

```
bar(epsilons , RMS(:,1));
```

Comment: obviously you're right, I really wanted a vector and not a matrix. I fixed it to  `RMS = zeros(1,length(epsilons))`. thanks!